# ReferenceError: index is not defined (Node.js, Express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, handler

I am basically trying to use express & hbs for rendering pages dynamically. I have also included the essential npm packages. I have also created index.hbs inside views directory but when I try to run my code, I get the following error.

```
ReferenceError: index is not defined
    at C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\src\app.js:11:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (C:\Users\Moaz\Desktop\Node JS Code\web-server\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (node:events:376:20)
```

app.js code: -

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath));

app.get("", (req, res) => {
  res.render(index);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Service is up and running successfully!");
});
```

Screenshot of VS Code directories: -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering the index page wrong, you need to pass a string to the render function, try `res.render('index');` on line 11.

Secondly your path me be wrong, put the views folder in your src folder and run the application. Or maybe adjust your path according to web-server/views/

Answer (score 1):

You write `index` as a variable.

Set it as a string :

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```